# How to create an attribute that will be incremented each time the class is being inherited. Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm looking for an answer how to increment superclass id attribute each time subclass(not object) is being created.

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, id, name, level, rarity):
        self.id = id
        # attributes


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # attributes


class Armor(Item):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Wooden_sword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(id=0, # **attributes=value)


class Wooden_armor(Armor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(id=1, # **attributes=value)


class Wooden_bow(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(id=2, # **attributes=value)
```

But I want it to be automatic, because I have a function which searches an object by it's id.

Can this be done using database?

Comment: Can you give some examples of classes and the `id` attribute they would end up with?

Comment: So, do you mean that the order of declaration of the different classes in this file above determines the id, independent of which class is their subclass?

Comment: What you mean as 'above'? But yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: @quamrana I think this is imposible, isn't it?

Comment: I'm looking into meta-classes atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one idea I had. You can create a `meta` class which can be used to intercept the creation of the class itself. Here, and this is my simplistic attempt, you can see whether the class name has an `'_'` in it, eg. `Wooden_bow` and for these classes only assign an `id` member to the class itself.

You may want a different strategy of assigning ids.

```py
#soClassId
#You need to get the subclasses to increment the id:

class MyMeta(type):
    id = 0
    def __new__(cls, classname, supers, classdict):
        print(f"meta: creating {classname} {supers}")
        ret = type.__new__(cls, classname, supers, classdict)
        if '_' in classname:
            i = MyMeta.id
            MyMeta.id = i + 1
            ret.id = i
        return ret

    __repr__ = lambda c: c.__name__
    
class Item(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, name, level, rarity):
        print(f'{self.__class__.__name__} {self.id}')


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Armor(Item):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Wooden_sword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Wooden_armor(Armor):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

#name=0, level=0, rarity=0
s = Wooden_sword(name=0, level=0, rarity=0)
a = Wooden_armor(name=0, level=0, rarity=0)

a = Wooden_armor(name=0, level=0, rarity=0)
s = Wooden_sword(name=0, level=0, rarity=0)
```

Output:

```
meta: creating Item ()
meta: creating Weapon (Item,)
meta: creating Armor (Item,)
meta: creating Wooden_sword (Weapon,)
meta: creating Wooden_armor (Armor,)
Wooden_sword 0
Wooden_armor 1
Wooden_armor 1
Wooden_sword 0
```

The above shows a diagnostic of when the classes themselves are created, and then when the instances are created that the `id` relates to the class and not the instance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with my classmethod which search and object by its id, but this is a smart solution, I can't imagine anything else